# Minimum value of a linear program

Tags: inequality, linear-programming

$x$ and $y$ are real numbers such that $ x\ge 0$ and $y \ge 0$.

If $$ x + y \le 5$$
$$ x + 2y \ge 8$$

Then what is the minimum value of $5x+y$?

There is something wrong in my approach.
I write the first inequality as $$ 5 \ge x + y$$
Adding with the second inequality yields, $$5 + x + 2y \ge x + y + 8$$
Or $$ y \ge 3$$ Thus $$ 9y \ge 27$$
Multiplying the second inequality by $5$ we obtain $$ 5x + 10y \ge 40$$ $$9y \ge 27$$
Hence $5x+y \ge 13$

Comment: You can add the equations $5x+10y \geq 40$ and $9y \geq 27$ to conclude $5 x+19 y  \geq 67$ but you can't subtract them and conclude anything meaningful. For example, we have $5 \geq 3$ and $5 \geq 2$ but you can't subtract the second from the first and say $0 \geq 1$.

Comment: So, how do you find the minimum value?

Comment: @Atiq Rahman I think, you are right. $13$ is a minimal value.

Comment: I got $$5x+y\geq 4$$ for $x=0,y=4$

Comment: $4$ is the minimum value @MichaelRozenberg . $(x,y)=(0,4)$ satisfies those inequalities.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Please write down the process.

Comment: You must plot the functions $$y=5-x,y=4-\frac{1}{2}x$$

Comment: @Atiq Rahman I found a mistake in my computations. The answer is $4$. See my post now.

Answer (score 1):

Our conditions give an interior of $\Delta ABC$,where $A(2,3)$, $B(0,5)$ and $C(0,4).$

The system $x=0$ and $x+2y=8$ gives $C(0,4)$;

The system $x=0$ and $x+y=5$ gives $B(0,5)$

and the system $x+y=5$ and $x+2y=8$ gives $A(2,3).$

Let $f(x,y)=5x+y.$

Thus, $$\min_{x\geq0,y\geq0,x+y\leq5,x+2y\geq8}f=\min\{f(0,5),f(0,4),f(2,3)\}=f(0,4)=4.$$

Comment: How do you find the points $(0,5),(0,4),(2,3)$?

Comment: @Atiq Rahman I added something. See now.